# AngularJS how to show browser dialog protects before changing tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events, alert

I have to display a message which warns the user before changing tab without saving changes. An url in the browser does not change in this process because user changes only a tab.

SetPristine, SetDirty will not help me because the url does not change. Is there any way to display this system-browser popup manually? If not maybe can you tell me how to create identical alert in the same space (it is placed in top-center part of the website).

I would like to get a result similar to the picture below.

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your asking for is not an Angular only thing. You can do it in pure javascript.

What you're asking about is the `beforeUnload` event.

Here is some sample code from [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload):

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  var confirmationMessage = "\o/";

  e.returnValue = confirmationMessage;     // Gecko, Trident, Chrome 34+
  return confirmationMessage;              // Gecko, WebKit, Chrome <34
});
```

This example prevents a dialog box, but to show one you need to set the return value to your dialog text:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  var confirmationMessage = "\o/";
  return "You will loose any unsaved changes, by leaving the page"
});
```

Another [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) page explains in more detail

What this means is you can put other code in the event handler that will pop up a modal say, or some other dialog to inform the user about data loss.

---

If what you want is actually about changing **tab**, then the cleanest way is to use the [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) which is [reasonably well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pagevisibility) now.

What you want is now more like so:

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but our system is SPA (single page application) and warning dialog should appear when the users selects another tab. Thats why the url does not changes so the event "beforeunload" is not fired.

Is there any way to trigger this event or angulars event e.g.(locationChangeStart) ?

Comment: @Ellbar what your describing is nothing to do with `locationChangeStart`, the url is the same *for that tab*. It's still 'loaded', what you're asking about is quite different to what I thought. You shouldn't lose any data just by changing tabs...

Comment: This is requirement to display protection before leaving selected tab without saving data. I know that I can easily display custom dialog, but I want to do identical alert like you get while leaving website. We use 'angular-unsavedChanges' in our project.

Comment: @Ellbar did you see my changes?